# Input file in wideimage

Tags: php, html, image, input

I have these codes. In `form.html`:

```
<form name="form2" method="post" action="lagarto.php" />
<input type="file" size="32" name="myimg" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

and in `lagarto.php`:

```
 <?php 

require( "./lib/WideImage.php");

$myimg = $_FILES['myimg']['tmp_name'];  // <-- Note this addition
$image = WideImage::load($myimg);



$image = WideImage::load($img);


$image->output('jpg', 90);

    ?>
```

It should show the image output but I got this error message:

> Notice: Undefined index: myimg in C:\Arquivos de
>   programas\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\wideimage-11.02.19-full\lagarto.php on
>   line 6
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught exception
>   'WideImage_InvalidImageSourceException' with message 'String doesn't
>   contain image data.' in C:\Arquivos de
>   programas\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\wideimage-11.02.19-full\lib\WideImage.php:240
>   Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: WideImage::loadFromString(NULL)
>    #1 C:\Arquivos de programas\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\wideimage-11.02.19-full\lib\WideImage.php(184):
>   call_user_func(Array, NULL) #2 C:\Arquivos de
>   programas\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\wideimage-11.02.19-full\lagarto.php(8):
>   WideImage::load(NULL) #3 {main} thrown in C:\Arquivos de
>   programas\EasyPHP-5.3.9\www\wideimage-11.02.19-full\lib\WideImage.php
>   on line 240

Any idea?

EDIT:
I tried to add these lines to my code:

```
$_FILES = $HTTP_POST_FILES;
$img = $FILES['myimg']['tmp_name'];
```

I tried even only one of the lines. And nothing changed.

Comment: I updated my code without success... any idea?

Answer (score 0):

`$myimg` isn't automatically set based on the form, and you never declared it.

You'll need something like to define `$myimg`:

```
$myimg = $_FILES['myimg']['tmp_name'];  // <-- Note this addition
$image = WideImage::load($myimg);
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember I had same problem. The solution was copying the image form system temp folder to local one and then access it via loader. (Another reason can be bad file suffix in temporary name.)

Comment: I'll try what you said. Thank you.

But I'm still looking for another solution or another explanation. Thanks